# Checking and Unchecking multiple checkbox from one checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently using this to check multiple checkbox values from one on a main sheet and checkbox values on the linked DB5 sheet.

I unsure of a way to get it down to a single true false check to condense this if( b && e.value == "TRUE") // <<< can i get this down to a single var to check if true

any help would be appreciated

```
[Copy to clipboard]

function DB2(e)
{
  if(!(e.range.getA1Notation()=='D17'&& e.range.getSheet().getName()=='DB2')){return}

  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var DB2 = ss.getSheetByName("DB2");
  
  var a  = DB2.getRange("D17").getValue();
  var b  = DB2.getRangeList(['D17']);

  var DB5 = ss.getSheetByName("DB5");

  //if('DB2' && b && e.value == "TRUE") // works

  if( b && e.value == "TRUE") // <<< can i get this down to a single var to check if true
  {
    DB2.getRange("D26").check();
    DB2.getRange("D28:D29").check();
  }
  else
  { 
  DB2.getRange("D26").uncheck();    
  DB2.getRange("D28:D29").uncheck();
  }

  if(b && e.value == "TRUE")
  {
    DB5.getRange("D15").check();
    DB5.getRange("H15").check();
  }
  else
  { 
  DB5.getRange("D15").uncheck();    
  DB5.getRange("H15").uncheck();
  }
}
```

Tried a few different ways to work this out but no luck so far

Comment: There's ambiguity about the logic statement you want to resolve. The first line is mean to exclude any edit other than in cell D17, sheet=DB2. But you focus on `if( b && e.value == "TRUE"){`. `e.value` is a checkbox (in cell D17 on sheet DB2) that has been checked (i.e. the value = true), but what do you understand by `b`. It's value is `DB2.getRangeList(['D17']);` which means nothing much unless you actually do something with it.  Then you have two similar `if` statements which could be easily combined. Would you please describe (in words) EXACTLY what logic you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I did not even think to just use if( e.value == "TRUE")  the second if statement was me testing if I could indeed change the other sheets values from the original sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You want a single logic statement for your script.

The following answer evaluates:

- whether a checkbox in cell D17 of sheet=DB2 was checked (value = true)

Just for fun, the cells to be checked/unchecked are defined by:

- `DB2.getRangeList` and `DB5.getRangeList(['D15', 'H15'])`
  But this could just as easily have been done using your existing `check`/`uncheck methods.`

Note: The function should be triggered by an installable `onEdit` trigger.

---

```
function DB2_04(e){

  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var DB2 = ss.getSheetByName("DB2");
  var DB5 = ss.getSheetByName("DB5");
  var checkListDB2 = DB2.getRangeList(['D26', 'D28:D29'])
  var checklistDB5 = DB5.getRangeList(['D15', 'H15'])
  
  var editedcell = e.range.getA1Notation()
  var editedsheet = e.range.getSheet().getName()
  var editedvalue = e.value
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited cell: "+editedcell+", edited sheet: "+editedsheet+" , edited value: "+editedvalue)

  if((editedcell == "D17") && (editedsheet =='DB2') && (editedvalue == "TRUE")){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: PASS: cell=D17 & true & sheet=DB2")
    checkListDB2.check();
    checklistDB5.check();    
  }
  else
  { 
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: FAIL: cell<>D17 &/or true &/or sheet=DB2")
    checkListDB2.uncheck();
    checklistDB5.uncheck();
  }
}
```